# Writing JSON arrays on multiple lines using Jackson in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I started to use Jackson a few days ago and I find this library super powerful, but there is something I couldn't manage to do : write arrays on multiple lines.

I have the following code :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;

public class App {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        ArrayNode node = mapper.createArrayNode();
        
        node.add("1");
        node.add("2");
        node.add("3");
        
        try {
            System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(node));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

With that I get this :

```
[ "1", "2", "3" ]
```

But I want this :

```
[ 
   "1",
   "2",
   "3"
]
```

How could I do that ?

Thanks

PS sorry if I did mistakes, English isn't my native language